# Self-hosted runner is not finding nvm or Node which are already installed in Linux

Tags: node.js, linux, github-actions, nvm

I have a Linux server at my home that has a GitHub Actions runner with the following code:

```
name: Build and Deploy UI - DEV

on:
  workflow_dispatch:
  push:
    branches: [ "dev" ]
    paths:
      - 'UI/**'
  pull_request:
    branches: [ "dev" ]
    paths:
      - 'UI/**'

jobs:
  build_and_deploy:
    if: github.ref == 'refs/heads/dev'
    runs-on: self-hosted
    steps:
    - name: Checkout
      uses: actions/checkout@v4      

    - name: Install Dependencies
      run: |        
        nvm list
        node -v
        npm -v
```

It is giving me this error

```
/github/actions-runner/project/_work/_temp/dc7e7354-9aa9-4676-8b50-883e4f150b34.sh:
line 2: nvm: command not found Error: Process completed with exit code 127.
```

I have tried using `nvm` and `node` installed as root and non-root (user running GitHub Actions) but nothing changes in the error message.

Can GitHub Actions use Node.js installed in the server? I don't want to set up Node.js and nvm every time I commit my code to save deployment time.

Comment: I had googled but could not find any information regarding using the already installed npm. But then copiolet comes to the rescue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was that the already installed Node and NVM were not available in the new terminal, which was by default shell (/bin/sh) for the non-root user. You can source the NVM to resolve this issue.

In my case, to solve this I performed the following operations.

1. Changed the default shell to bash (/bin/bash) for non-root user

   ```
   sudo chsh -s /bin/bash non-root
   ```
2. Added .profile (actually copied code from /root path)

   ```
   if [ "$BASH" ]; then
      if [ -f ~/.bashrc ]; then
         . ~/.bashrc
      fi
   fi

   mesg n 2> /dev/null || true
   ```
3. Added .bashrc files

   ```
   export HISTCONTROL=ignoreboth:erasedups

   export NVM_DIR="$HOME/.nvm"
   [ -s "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh"  # This loads nvm
   [ -s "$NVM_DIR/bash_completion" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/bash_completion"  # This loads nvm bash_completi>
   ```
4. Added BASH_ENV: ~/.profile in action runner

   ```
   name: Build and Deploy UI - Prod

   on:
     workflow_dispatch:
     push:
       branches: [ "main" ]
       paths:
         - 'UI/**'
     pull_request:
       branches: [ "main" ]
       paths:
         - 'UI/**'

   env:
     BASH_ENV: ~/.profile

   jobs:
     build_and_deploy:
       if: github.ref == 'refs/heads/main'
       runs-on: self-hosted
       steps:
       - name: Checkout
         uses: actions/checkout@v4      

       - name: Install Dependencies
         run: |
           cd ./path-to-project-root
           npm ci
   ```